# Why no Stub in REST?

Tags: rest, soap, rpc

**EDIT** : My original title was "Use of Stub in RPC" ; I edited the title just to let others know it is more than that question.

I have started developing some SOAP based services and I cannot understand the role of stubs. To quote Wiki :

> The client and server use different address spaces, so conversion of parameters used in a function call have to be performed, otherwise the values of those parameters could not be used, because of pointers to the computer's memory pointing to different data on each machine. The client and server may also use different data representations even for simple parameters (e.g., big-endian versus little-endian for integers.) Stubs are used to perform the conversion of the parameters, so a Remote Function Call looks like a local function call for the remote computer.

This is dumb, but I don't understand this "practically". I have done some socket programming in Java, but I don't remember any step for "conversion of parameters" when my TCP/UDP clients interacted with my server. (I assume raw server-client communication using TCP/UDP sockets does come under RPC)

I have had some experience with RESTful service development, but I can't recognize the Stub analogue with REST either. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: A better title might be, "What are stubs used for?"

Comment: FYI, the concept of a "stub" is an RPC concept. SOAP web services also support a "document" style of interaction, which does not use the term "stub". Parameters are not involved in such an interaction, but rather documents are exchanged.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : How can documents un-necessitate the need of stubs ? Can you please link some read ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stubs for calls over the network (be they SOAP, REST, CORBA, DCOM, JSON-RPC, or whatever) are just helper classes that give you a wrapper function that takes care of all the underlying details, such as:

- Initializing your TCP/UDP/whatever transport layer
- Finding the right address to call and doing DNS lookups if needed
- Connecting to the network endpoint where the server should be
- Handling errors if the server isn't listening
- Checking that the server is what we're expecting it to be (security checks, versioning, etc)
- Negotiating the encoding format
- Encoding (or "marshalling") your request parameters in a format suitable for transmission on the network (CDR, NDR, JSON, XML, etc.)
- Transmitting your encoded request parameters over the network, taking care of chunking or flow control as necessary
- Receiving the response(s) from the server
- Decoding (or "unmarshalling") the response details
- Returning the responses to your original calling code (or throwing an error if something went wrong)

There's no such thing as "raw" TCP communication. If you are using it in a request/response model and infer any kind of meaning from the data sent across the TCP connection then you've encoded some form of "parameters" in there. You just happened to build yourself what stubs would normally have provided.

Stubs try to make your remote calls look just like local in-process calls, but honestly that's a really bad thing to do. They're not the same at all, and they should be considered differently by your application.